# How to set externalLinkTarget to _BLANK

Tags: pdf.js

In some previous version of PDF.js we used to have the following setting in viewer.html:

```
PDFJS.externalLinkTarget = PDFJS.LinkTarget.BLANK;
```

It caused all the links being opened in new tab instead of the same window. After upgrade to the latest version (2.3), it stopped working.

I tried this as well - but no luck:

```
PDFViewerApplication.preferences.set('externalLinkTarget', 2);
```

[image]

The only way to make it work is modifying the core pdf.js file viewer.js - method getDefaultPreferences

```
"externalLinkTarget": 2,
```

I can't find anywhere why this settings stopped working and what is the correct syntax now. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found the solution, the old syntax is apparently no longer supported since pdf.js 2.0.943, this piece of code does what I need - it changes the default behavior of links opening to open then in new window.

```
<script>
    function applyConfig() {
        PDFViewerApplication.preferences.set('externalLinkTarget', 2);
    }
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', applyConfig, true);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone self-hosting the PDFJS files, the `externalLinkTarget` default can be changed in `viewer.js` BasePreferences:

```
class BasePreferences {
    constructor() {
        Object.defineProperty(this, "defaults", {
            value: Object.freeze({
                "annotationMode": 2,
                "enablePermissions": false,
                "enablePrintAutoRotate": true,
                "enableScripting": true,
                "externalLinkTarget": 2,  // 2 = BLANK
                "historyUpdateUrl": false,
                "ignoreDestinationZoom": false,
                "pdfBugEnabled": false,
                "renderer": "canvas",
```

There is also a value set in defaultOptions but this seemed to have no effect:

```
const defaultOptions = {
    externalLinkRel: {
           value: "noopener noreferrer nofollow",
           kind: OptionKind.VIEWER
       },
       externalLinkTarget: {
           value: 2, // 2 = BLANK
           kind: OptionKind.VIEWER + OptionKind.PREFERENCE
       },
```