# When using a HTML <object> to display a PDF file, is there any way to make links open in new tab (like target = _blank)

Tags: html, pdf

When displaying a PDF file within a HTML page using the  element:

```
<object type="application/pdf" data="path-to-file.pdf"></object>
```

Any web links in the PDF file open by default in the same browser tab, replacing the entire webpage or web app. Not really what is wanted in a complex React SPA.

Is there any way to force these links in the embedded PDF to open in a new tab, as if they had target="_blank"?

Solutions, even browser specific, most welcome!

Note: we do already have an option to replace the native PDF renderer with PDFJS - that works OK (and is necessary on Safari) but is significantly slower, so want to avoid it whereever possible.

Comment: Makes sense really. I ended up switching to PDFJS, and changing their default by editing in the code as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/77839755/1580110